# single period security market with two assets

Tags: risk, portfolio-optimization, risk-management, risk-neutral-measure, optimal-hedge-ratio

Consider a single period security market with two assets. Assume the current prices
are[image]

There are two states at time one and the payoff matrix is
[image]

1.Suppose the investor believes that each state has equal probability. Assume an
investor’s initial wealth is w0 = 10, and her utility function is u(x) = log(x). Solve the optimal portfolio selection problem for this agent and verify the optimal solution exists.

2.Find the risk-neutral probability measure for this agent.

please please help me

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: tried on paper(a mess, failed